# setting false to [checkbox] DOM property not unchecking the checkbox in Angular

Tags: html, angular, checkbox

I am trying to uncheck **Time in Loop** checkbox  when user clicks the **stop** radio button, but **Time in Loop** checkbox not unchecking.

Stackblitz url - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s3ryzm?file=src/app/app.component.html

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Click **GotoStream** radio button.
2. Select **Time in Loop** checkbox
3. Click **Stop** radio button, **Time in Loop** checkbox must be unchecked, but it not unchecked.

Below is the template view.

```
<div class="form-group ml-3">
  <div class="radio">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" checked [disabled]="Stop" (change)="dropDownStream=true; timeInLoopChecked=false; timeInLoop=true; timeInLoopInput=true" >&nbsp;Stop
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio" >
    <label class="float-left w-25 mt-2 mr-2">
      <input type="radio" name="optradio" [disabled]="goToStream" (change)="dropDownStream = false; timeInLoopChecked=false; timeInLoop=false; timeInLoopInput=true" >&nbsp;GotoStream
    </label>
    <select class="custom-select float-left" style="width: 70%;" [disabled] = "dropDownStream">
      <option selected>Open this select menu</option>
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="form-group vertical-group ml-3" style="clear: both;">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="float-left w-25 mt-2 mr-2">
      <input type="checkbox" value="" [checked]="timeInLoopChecked" [disabled]="timeInLoop" (change)="timeInLoopInput=!timeInLoopInput" >&nbsp;&nbsp;Time in Loop
    </label>
    <input class="float-left" style="width: 70%;" placeholder="0" type="text" class="form-control" id="streamName"  autocomplete="off" [disabled]="timeInLoopInput"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is the component file:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  dropDownStream: boolean = true;
  timeInLoop: boolean = true;
  Stop: boolean=false;
  goToStream: boolean = false;
  timeInLoopInput: boolean = true;
  timeInLoopChecked: boolean = false;
}
```

How to make **Time in Loop** checkbox gets unchecked when user clicks **stop** radio button?

Thanks,
Mohan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changed this line :

```
 <input type="radio" name="optradio" [disabled]="goToStream" (change)="dropDownStream = false; timeInLoopChecked=true; timeInLoop=false; timeInLoopInput=true" >&nbsp;GotoStream
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mbwfy2?file=src/app/app.component.html

You are not toggling `timeInLoopChecked` on radio button.